# How To Use groupBy in whereHas laravel

Tags: laravel, meta, wherehas

i am using [Metable](https://laravel-metable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_meta.html) in my project for creating meta for orders
but i have one problem
i want group orders that have same email
this is metable table image : [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXxzx.png) [image 2](https://ibb.co/PFvXxNd)

i need code like this can work :)

```
Order::whereHas( 'meta', function($query) {
        $query->where("key" , "gmail");
})->groupBy('meta.value')->get();
```

and this is meta relation that called by trait 'use Metable' in Order Model:

```
public function meta(): MorphMany
{
    return $this->morphMany($this->getMetaClassName(), 'metable');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query may work, we start querying from the Meta model:

```
Meta::with('metable')
    ->whereHasMorph('metable', Order::class)
    ->where('key', 'gmail')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('value')
    ->map(function ($metaCollection) {
        return $metaCollection->map->metable->unique('id');
    });
```

Comment: it not worked :(  |  said Property [value] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Can you post a different image of the meta table that reveals all column names?

Comment: I know why it failed and updated the answer accordingly, pls check.

Comment: tnx dude , it's workd :) there is anyway that get them from Order not Meta?

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I would give it a try to retrive the models from the Order class:

```php
Order::whereHas('meta', function($query) {
    $query->where('key', 'gmail');
})->with(['meta' => function($query) {
    $query->groupBy('value')
}])->get();
```

Comment: not worked , this code returnd all objects that have meta ! and groupby not worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution instead:

```
Order::whereHas( 'meta', function($query) {
    $query->where("key" , "gmail")
    $query->groupBy('meta.value');
})->get();
```